# Line graphs in matplotlib

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I am plotting the below data frame using google charts.

```
Hour S1 S2  S3
1   174 0   811
2   166 0   221
3   213 1   1061
```

But with google charts, I am not able to save it to a file. Just wondering whether I can plot the dataframe in matplotlib line charts.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pandas has charting method, just do:

```
df.plot()
```

where df is your pandas dataframe

Answer (score 1):

matplotlib 1.5 and above supports a `data` wkarg

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot('S1', 'S2', data=df)
```

or just directly pass in the columns as input

```
ax.plot(df['S1'])
```